# Отсечение группы записей

Tags: sql

Провести отсечение определенного числа записей, содержащие min и max значение параметра, параметр упорядочен по возрастанию.

Comment: неоптимальный вариант через временные таблицы: получить 90% бОльших и 90% меньших, сделать между ними inner join.

Comment: а БД кто указывать будет? или вам брутфорсом ответы под каждую давать будут?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from t
where P > (select min(P) from t)
and P < (select max(P) from t);
```

Comment: Нет надо отсечь четко определенное число min и max значений - например 10% от общего количества 
пример:
SELECT w.pid  -- отсечение весов  5% 
                                  FROM #temp_pid w CROSS JOIN #temp_pid v
                                  GROUP BY w.pid
                                  HAVING COUNT (CASE WHEN v.pid <= w.pid THEN 1 ELSE null END) > @count_t/20
                                  and COUNT (CASE WHEN v.pid >= w.pid THEN 1 ELSE null END) > @count_t/20)

дело в том, что после операции cross join по возрастанию по PID

а это не правильное отсечение

Answer (score 0):

```
with qty
as
(select COUNT(*) qty from T),
num as
(select ROW_NUMBER () over(order by val) n,* from T)

select * from num, qty where n between qty*0.1 and qty*0.9
```